# Paypal integration with ASP.NET MVC code to approve separately with a delay

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I want to use Paypal APIs for payment integration in this way.

Person A sends a payment to Person B. Person B will not get money unless person A finally presses the approve button after few days.